# "Use screen saver" switch doesn't stay ON

Tags: settings, screen-timeout

I've got my first real Android device (until now only Android-x86 and Waydroid on PC) - a tablet and now I'm encountering some problems and googling doesn't help. First day I did set up the device, I know the screen saver showing clock was working. And then it just started to turn black. In the meantime I didn't do much changes. One thing I did I installed "System UI tuner" to be able to show seconds in status bar. I seem to remember that the screen saver worked after that because I thought about it not showing seconds.
Now I don't understand what happened but I cannot turn "Use screen saver" switch ON - when I tap it it launches screensaver, then I tap on the screen, the screen saver stops and the switch is OFF. After the inactivity timeout the screen goes black.
It is the same if I choose colors instead of clock, the same for different "When to start". I even tried to add a new user with default settings, anyway the screen goes black.
Android 12, a tablet
[image: Use screen saver switch]

Comment: Dors ot not sound lime the fault of the System UI Tuner, to you?  Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @RohitGupta yes, of course, doesn't change anything. Btw for the new user there is no this app, no seconds in status bar, and anyway black screen.